# Weird transposing after dot product and transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm reading a paragraph in a book where a plane equation ($N\cdot Q + D = 0$, N being the normal and D the distance from the origin, Q any point which belongs to the plane) is transformed by a matrix M and a translation T and I don't understand a mathematical passage:

[image]

The lines above are transforming the N normal vector by the transposed inverse of a generic transformation matrix M. T is an additional translation (N isn't added to T since directions aren't translated anywhere).

Dot product is distributive so the second line makes sense.. but I don't understand where did those transpose come from. Why do we need them? I don't get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have two vectors $\vec a = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $\vec b = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, we can consider them to be column matrices

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0 \end{bmatrix} \ 
\text{and} \
B = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, the dot product $\vec a \cdot \vec b$ becomes

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_0 & y_0 & z_0 \end{bmatrix} \times
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{bmatrix} = A^T \times B = A^TB
$$

Note that $\times$ is the **matrix product** and *not* the vector cross product.

Hence, the dot product

$$
-((M^{-1})^T N) \cdot (MP + T) = \\
-((M^{-1})^T N) \cdot MP + -((M^{-1})^T N) \cdot T = \\
-((M^{-1})^T N)^T \times MP -((M^{-1})^T N) \times T 
$$

Which is the desired expression

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense and I learned something new.

Comment: no problem :) You may also see a similar transform, where you can express the cross product $\vec a \times \vec b$ as the product of two matrices, usually denoted $A^\times \times B$, where $A^\times$ is the "cross product matrix. Just that I should warn you in advance!